# Can I store soft serve ice cream in my regular freezer?

Tags: freezing, refrigerator, ice-cream

I was gifted with a soft serve ice cream dispenser. however it's such a pain to always keep the machine on and running each time I want ice cream--more so that it highly consumes electricity. I wish to know if there is a way I can produce my soft serve in a large quantity and store it in my freezer so I can always remove and take a scoop each time I want soft serve. I tried it once but it went hard as a rock and lost its texture when I allowed it to defreeze.

Is there a trick to keeping it soft and close to the consistency in the freezer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard recommended temperature for a home freezer is 0°F (-18℃). Regular ice cream keeps best at -5°F to 0°F. However, the proper storage temperature for soft serve ice cream is 18°F (-7℃).

While you could raise the temperature of your freezer to accommodate this, it really wouldn't be recommended for the rest of your frozen foods.

Short of that, your best option would be to get a tiny freezer just for your soft serve so that you can keep it at at higher temperature without risking the quality of your other food.

Comment: Thanks. tried that but at some point ice crystals starts to develop. it must not really maintain the soft serve consistency, i can always welcome it going to the level of a regular ice cream while maintaining its creaminess. i just dont want it to go hard rock so that it becomes impossible to scoop

Comment: someone advised me to use corn syrup and corn starch in my mixture. i know of that in regular ice cream but will that really work with soft serve?